# How to delete an empty line from text file in C++?

Tags: c++

I've been learning programming for about a year now in college and I've learned some stuff along the way so I decided to make my very own **"Host editor"** program which basically edits your windows hosts file, lets you insert, remove and manage the URLs inside. :)

However, I've ran into problems when trying to delete a URL from the file. I'm not actually deleting it since I don't know how to do it, but I create a new empty text file and then copy all the lines except the one with the URL that I wish to delete. Sounds reasonable?

It appears, however, that I can't delete the URL without leaving inside a so-called **"empty line"**. At least not with how I've coded it... I've tried everything and I really need your help.

But please, use "noob friendly" language with me here, I won't understand any complicated terms :)

Thank you, and here's my full code:

http://joggingbenefits.net/hcode.txt

and here's just the part of the code that I think is messing with me (delete URL function):

```
void del(int lin)  // line index
{
    FILE* fp=fopen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts","r+");
    FILE* fp1=fopen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts1","w");

    char str[200];
    int cnt=0;

    while(! feof(fp))
    {
        fgets(str,200,fp);


        if(str[0]=='#')
        {
            fputs(str,fp1);
        }
        else
        {
            if(cnt==lin)
            {               // problem. FLAG?!
                cnt++;
            }
            else
            {
                    cnt++;
                    fputs(str,fp1);
            }

        }

    }



    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);

    rename("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts","C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\deleteme");
    rename("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts1","C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
    remove("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\deleteme");

    cout << endl << "LINE DELETED!" << endl;

}
```

Comment: You should really try to post the relevant code here. For that, try to come up with a minimal example that demonstrates your unwanted behavior and post that here. This will also help you understand it better yourself. Besides that, if you really want to program in C++ I would recommend you start using C++ streams for file-I/O.

Comment: I did try, but the editor is honestly terrible. It says click here to insert code, then I insert my code and it formats it terribly, putting some bits in code and other bits in normal text. It also says press TAB and '$', however when I press TAB, it jumps to the tag texbox at the bottom of the page... what can I say

Comment: You just have to paste the code, highlight it, and then click on *format as code*.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have tagged this as C++, I'll assume that you want to rewrite it to eliminate the C `FILE` interface.

```
std::ifstream in_file("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
std::ofstream out_file("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts1");

std::string line;
while ( getline( in_file, line ) ) {
    if ( ! line.empty() ) {
        out_file << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/ZibDT

Very straightforward!

Comment: This program removes empty lines. If you want to filter lines on some other condition, just use that instead of `line.empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said *how* this code fails (or given us some text as an example), but I notice a problem with your loop. The "end of file" condition is caused by the act of trying to read past the end of the file, but you do the test (`feof`) *before* the `fgets`, so you operate on the last line twice: control enters the loop after the last line is read, tries -- and fails -- to read another line, acts on the line still in `str`, and then terminates the loop.

Instead of

```
while(! feof(fp))
  {
    fgets(str,200,fp))
    ...
```

try:

```
while(fgets(str,200,fp))
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Reason

`fgets()` function reads line including trailing end-of-line character (`'\n'`), while `puts()` function writes line passed to in **and** end-of-line character. So if you read

`this line`

it's stored as

`this line\n`

in `str`. And is written back to the file as

`this line\n\n`

which looks like this

`this line`

in the file.

## Fix

- Use `fprintf(fp2, "%s", str);`
- Remove trailing `"\n"` in `str` before using `fputs()`.